# How to delete message.info in python django after refreshing the page?

Tags: python, html, django, registration

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('register:index')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Username or password incorrect.")

    return render(request, 'login/login.html')
```

login.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="poster">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="input-group mb-4">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></span>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" type="text" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-4">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></span>
    <input type="password" id="myInput" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" data-toggle="password">                  
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-4 d-grid">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show password" style="color: aliceblue;" id="show"> 
  </div>
  

  <div class="d-grid">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
    <br>
    <p class="text-center">
      Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register:index' %}">Sign up</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</form>
{% if messages %}
                  <ul class="messages">
                      {% for message in messages %}
                          <li style="list-style-type: none; color:rgb(195, 67, 67);">
                              {{ message }}
                          </li>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I don't know how to make clear page after refreshing. The message "Username or password incorrect." is always displaying after inputs was incorrect.

I've gooogled this problem but it seems to be that everyone pass this problem somehow :/

Comment: When you refresh the page you are probably re-submitting the bad form values, causing a fresh message to get displayed (web browsers do this automatically when you refresh the result of a POST request).  Try append `?` to the url and hit enter instead of refreshing, this should make a fresh GET request to the page instead of re-submitting the POST... if the message is gone then it means that was probably the problem.

Comment: @Anentropic it worked! But next question is how can I make GET method everytime I reload the page instead of every time appending "quastion sign"?

Comment: why do you need to?  I think refreshing the page when you get an error is not something that users need to do, it's probably just something you did when testing your own website

Comment: That's a good question :D Yo're 100% right.
Just realised that there is no reason to this error disappear. Thanks for answering!